# C# LINQ, need help about logic / algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I have a list of values, as below , the number at left side represents the object to be removed / inserted, where the "insert/remove" is action taken

```
1 insert
2 insert
3 insert
2 remove
4 insert
2 insert
3 remove
5 insert
3 insert
5 remove
```

And final result i want is "5 remove".

So if the position of removed object in list is bigger than position of same object from insert, then it will be removed, others will leave intact(1,2,3,4 will be inserted). can we do it with LINQ?

Comment: So you want us to implement this scenario for you, isn't it? Sorry to say that we are not providing code writing service

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand how the final result could be "5 remove" what about "1 insert" for example? According to your description, it should be left intact. The problem is very confusing. Moreover, it doesn't really sound like a LINQ scenario.

Comment: "So if the position of removed object in list is bigger than position of same object from insert, then it will be removed, others will leave intact." - What???

Comment: Please add sample data and also your first efforts. Maybe that will make clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have class `Operation` with 2 properties `ID` and `CRUD`

```
public class Operation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string CRUD { get; set; }
}

var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Last().CRUD);

//if you want to have same List<Operation>
list = list.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
            .Select(x=> new Operation { ID = x.Key, CRUD = x.Last().CRUD }).ToList();
```

Here [**dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VcdWFG)

**EDIT:**

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<Operation> list = new List<Operation>();

    Operation o1 = new Operation();
    o1.ID = 1;
    o1.CRUD = "Insert";
    list.Add(o1);

    Operation o2 = new Operation();
    o2.ID = 2;
    o2.CRUD = "Insert";
    list.Add(o2);

    Operation o3 = new Operation();
    o3.ID = 3;
    o3.CRUD = "Insert";
    list.Add(o3);

    Operation o4 = new Operation();
    o4.ID = 2;
    o4.CRUD = "Remove";
    list.Add(o4);

    Operation o5 = new Operation();
    o5.ID = 4;
    o5.CRUD = "Insert";
    list.Add(o5);

    Operation o6 = new Operation(){ID=2, CRUD = "Insert"};

    list.Add(o6);

    Operation o7= new Operation(){ID=3, CRUD = "Remove"};

    list.Add(o7);

    Operation o8= new Operation(){ID=5, CRUD = "Insert"};

    list.Add(o8);

    Operation o9= new Operation(){ID=3, CRUD = "Insert"};
    list.Add(o9);

    Operation o10= new Operation(){ID=5, CRUD = "Remove"};
    list.Add(o10);

    var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.ID).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Last().CRUD);

    foreach(var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ": " + item.Value);
    }

    list = list.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
        .Select(x=> new Operation { ID = x.Key, CRUD = x.Last().CRUD }).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("List values");

    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ID + ": " + item.CRUD);
    }

    //output for 5 is Remove.

}

public class Operation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string CRUD { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you apply this to the OP's data?

Comment: @Enigmativity and yes you can apply it.

Comment: I meant can you go ahead and edit your question to show the application of the OP's data. Right now there is no way to know if this answers the question or not. Linking to an external site should only be used to support content already in your question and not to add to it.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm really confuse by what you wrote here. DotNetFiddle is well know and like JSfiddle and other places is given to reproduce and show full solution. But Specially for you I will write the outputs too because you have problem to copy paste 10 records ! There is no way this and my previous answer to differ in any way. This makes the answer only **UNREADABLE** and **HARD** to understand

Comment: Use *both*. You can't guarantee that DotNetFiddle content has the same lifetime as your answer; the site could delete that link or disappear altogether. If your answer can't stand on its own without the DotNetFiddle content then it is not useful.

Comment: People are just trying to help you write higher quality answers. If you provide extra info, then sure, then not much is lost when a link goes down. You don't need to keep arguing when someone disagrees however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I disagree that this is relevant information to the problem. When I search for an answer of a problem I will never read the answer with 150 lines of code. I will always will read the 1-2-5 liners. You can tell for yourself which is more understandable code before the edit or code after the edit.

Comment: That's fine. What is not fine is then arguing your point with bolded capital text calling in question the motives of the messenger.

Comment: @MartijnPieters okay I will not use capitals in the future.

Comment: @mybirthname - Your answer should stand alone without the need of external references. It doesn't matter how unreadable or hard that might make your answer - self-reliance is more important to SO. Your answer will differ when you add the OP's data as it will show how your answer applies to the OP's question. That is paramount in making this an acceptable answer, not just for the OP, but for the SO community at large.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure to understand the question but yoiu can check if the higgest ID is equal to "remove", like that :

```
    public class MyList
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ToDo { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
    List<MyList> MyList = new List<MyList>();
    if ( MyList.OrderBy(c => c.Id).LastOrDefault().ToDo == "remove")
        {
            // Code to remove what need to be removed
        }
```

Comment: Could you apply this to the OP's data?